Get a warning from Google Page Speed ​Insight about page redirects
I made a script to redirect users who use browsers other than Indonesian. the script runs fine. But when I checked Google Page Speed ​​Insight I got a warning: The page may not be loading as expected because your test URL (https://www.my-website.com/) was redirected to https://www.my-website.com/en/ . Try testing the second URL directly.
how do I create a function so that the script I create will not run if the user is a bot / crawler / google bot, etc.
here is the script


// Mendeteksi bahasa browser pengguna
var userLanguage = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

// Mendapatkan preferensi bahasa pengguna dari localStorage
var preferredLanguage = localStorage.getItem('preferredLanguage');

// Mendapatkan timestamp terakhir dari redirect
var lastRedirectTime = localStorage.getItem('lastRedirectTime');
var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Waktu dalam milidetik untuk 24 jam

// Fungsi untuk melakukan redirect dengan pengecekan waktu
function redirectIfNeeded(url) {
    if (!lastRedirectTime || currentTime - lastRedirectTime > oneDay) {
        localStorage.setItem('lastRedirectTime', currentTime);
        window.location.href = url;
    }
}

// Jika tidak ada preferensi bahasa yang disimpan di localStorage
if (!preferredLanguage) {
    // Jika bahasa pengguna bukan bahasa Indonesia ('id')
    if (userLanguage !== 'id') {
        // Redirect ke halaman bahasa Inggris dengan pengecekan waktu
        redirectIfNeeded("https://www.my-website.com/en");
    }
} else {
    // Jika preferensi bahasa adalah bahasa Indonesia ('id')
    if (preferredLanguage === 'id') {
        // Redirect ke halaman bahasa Indonesia
        window.location.href = "https://www.my-website.com";
    }
}

// Fungsi untuk mengubah bahasa ke bahasa Indonesia dan menyimpan preferensi di localStorage
function changeToIndonesian() {
    localStorage.setItem('preferredLanguage', 'id');
    window.location.href = "https://www.my-website.com";
}

// Fungsi untuk mengubah bahasa ke bahasa Inggris dan menyimpan preferensi di localStorage
function changeToEnglish() {
    localStorage.setItem('preferredLanguage', 'en');
    window.location.href = "https://www.my-website/en";
}




All the warning said was that the URL for which you ran the check, redirected somewhere else - and that you should probably run it again for that second URL, to see what page speed evaluation that actually gets.

I have run Google Page Speed ​​twice on the same page but the warning from Google Page Speed ​​still appears, except on pages in English

will this be dangerous for seo?

userLanguage is probably not getting set to id in this scenario, I would assume, so you'd be redirecting to the English version every time then. Not sure how/ if you can recognize the Google crawler properly in this scenario - Google themself probably have an interest, in not being easily discoverable. (Plus, they might not like it if you treat their crawler differently, than normal clients.)

It is bad practice to automatically change the URL based on browser language settings.  Instead show a prominent notice in the page asking if the user wants to switch language.
It is bad for user experience to automatically change the language based on browser settings. Many users don't have their browsers configured correctly. These users won't be able to access your site.
Furthermore, as you are discovering, changing the language URL automatically hurts SEO. Crawlers and tools won't be able to access your site.
